# Is rails constant autoloading different depending on the environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing a Rails application(Rails4.2.5.1, Ruby2.2.3). In staging environment, some classes are not 
correctly recognized. In the other hand, in development environment, all classes are correctly recognized. The below is staging rails console's result.

```
$ bundle exec rails c staging
Running via Spring preloader in process 6940
Loading staging environment (Rails 4.2.5.1)
[1] pry(main)> StartTask
=> StartTask
[2] pry(main)> Japan::Tokyo::CheckTask
=> Japan::Tokyo::CheckTask (call 'Japan::Tokyo::CheckTask.connection' to establish a connection)
[3] pry(main)> Hoge::Fuga::SingleBase
=> Hoge::Fuga::SingleBase (call 'Hoge::Fuga::SingleBase.connection' to establish a connection)
[4] pry(main)> Hoge::Fuga::Base   
=> Hoge::Fuga::Base
[5] pry(main)> StartTask.superclass        
=> Hoge::Fuga::Base
[6] pry(main)> Japan::Tokyo::CheckTask.superclass
=> Hoge::Fuga::SingleBase (call 'Hoge::Fuga::SingleBase.connection' to establish a connection)
[7] pry(main)> Hoge::Fuga::SingleBase.superclass
=> Base(abstract)
[8] pry(main)> Hoge::Fuga::Base.superclass      
=> Object
```

I expect 'Hoge::Fuga::SingleBase.superclass' to return 'Hoge::Fuga::Base', but actual result is 'Base(abstract)'. And, I have some strange warning messages.('call xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx to establish a connection')

The below is related codes.

```
# app/tasks/start_task.rb
class StartTask < Hoge::Fuga::Base
  something...

# app/tasks/japan/tokyo/check_task.rb
module Japan
  module Tokyo
    class CheckTask < Hoge::Fuga::SingleBase
      something...

# lib/hoge/fuga/single_base.rb
module Hoge::Fuga
  class SingleBase < Base
    something...

# lib/hoge/fuga/base.rb
module Hoge::Fuga
  class Base
    something...

# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

Do you know reason?

Comment: It sounds like you're getting an unexpected superclass. You could make your question more clear by specifying exactly what class is reporting the wrong superclass.  This is likely related to Rails autoloading, and you should read http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/

Comment: Also, make sure you understand the subtleties of `config.auto_load_paths` _and_ `config.eager_load_paths`.  See http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/

Comment: Thank you very much, Nathan! I made my question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as *Rails constant resolution*. Constant resolution is defined in the Ruby Language Specification and implemented by the Ruby compiler or interpreter. Ruby does not allow changing the constant resolution algorithm from user code, so the constant resolution algorithm *cannot* possibly be different between different Rails environments.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I edited the question's title.

Comment: Are you aware of `const_missing`? That effectively lets you change constant resolution (for missing constants) from user code, and Rails _does_ handle missing constants differently in different Rails environments.

Comment: `const_missing` doesn't change the constant resolution algorithm. It's still "first outwards (lexically), then upwards (by inheritance)". It lets you intercept the case where constant lookup fails at a particular point during the lookup, but that is not the same as changing the order and/or place where Ruby looks up constants. It's the same as with `method_missing`: you can handle missing methods, but you cannot change the resolution. If you could, `Module#prepend` and Refinements wouldn't have needed a change of the Ruby Language Specification, they could have been provided as a library.

Comment: Rails doesn't change the constant resolution _algorithm_, but it _can_ change the actual constant _resolution_, which is likely what the OP is experiencing. Would you agree?